# A Very Easy Wordsquare Riddle

Tags: riddle, word-square

This is my first question.
Well, first on this website.
Just a simple word square
Packed in a riddle tight.

My first, he used to be ugly.
And Hans is his creator.
My second is just a word.
There are clues no more.

My third can be cramped and small.
Yet often he is wide.
My last is Bismarck and Phoenix.
This riddle is too easy, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probable solution:

> `S W A N`
> `W O R D`
> `A R E A`
> `N D A Z`
>
>  First: Hans Christian Andersen wrote the Ugly Duckling, about a `swan` who was once "ugly".
>  The second is just a `word`.
>  Third: an `area` can be small and cramped, or wide open.
>  Fourth, these are the capital cities of `ND` North Dakota and `AZ` Arizona

Comment: I knew this was way too easy! Did you do any googling?

Comment: Nope - the clues were pretty straightforward and common knowledge things - but fun to solve :)

Comment: I don't expect anyone to memorize capital of states! Btw thx for the compliment. I think this is the easiest puzzle to build. Should I make more?

Comment: For your next, it's better if all the "words" are actual words.  And welcome to puzzle-setting at PSE:)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Hope I can settle with this PSE environment!

Comment: But "ndaz" is an actual word -- Caesar-shifted by 15.

Comment: Didn't see that coming, Mr. Oehm! I'm sure I will use that substitution in the future.